# Windows 10 Sync Account Settings to Multiple Accounts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, user-accounts

**Preface**: All my accounts are Microsoft Accounts. And in Microsoft they have personal accounts and Work or School accounts. You can have a personal account be the same email address as a Work or School Account.

I first set up my PC with a personal @live.com account. Later I added another personal email account associated with my work. Then my work decided to adopt Office 365, creating a Work account with my same email address.

Because I initially started this computer with the @live.com account, everything is being synced to that account in the "Sync your Settings"  section under accounts.

My problem is that I now have a new laptop and I want to sync my settings from @live.com but I dont want that account on my new laptop. I instead, want to use my personal work account.

How can I migrate my settings from @live.com to my personal @{work}.com account?

Or how can I sync to multiple accounts?

Comment: For your personal computer I would highly reccomend using your personal account. It will save headaches down the road if you ever leave that job.

Comment: Thank you, however, I am Ok using a personal work associated email address account for this laptop. I just want my personal syncing settings moved to my personal work associated email address account.

Comment: You are more trusting than I am. My understanding is that even a personal email account that is through your employer can be locked by that employer. I'm happy to be wrong about that though.

Comment: @EBGreen they can not lock a personal account, but they can lock the Work account.

Comment: If you want to sync your settings between a work and personal account, it will involve, linking the account then unlinking it, and linking it to the other account.

Comment: @Ramhound you're exactly right. I did that and have finally come back to supply that answer to see your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this myself, by stumbling across an answer from Microsoft. I can't find the resource at this time but i'll keep looking and provide it later.

The steps I have taken were:

1. Link your initial account (this should already be completed as it's your primary account).
2. Switch to logging in as a local account.
3. Add your secondary account (different from the primary)
4. Configure Syncing on that secondary account.

When you switch to and from logging in as a local account, you maintain the profile settings from that primary account. So any additional accounts you add after the fact, will inherit those settings.